# Best way of getting WooCommerce category path

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

If I am on a product or any category/subcategory I want to display a complete path to the topmost category.
Does WooCommerce already have a function for it or do I need to make my own loop that goes from child to parent?
Should I use $wp_query->get_queried_object()?
What is the best code for it?

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may look for breadcrumb?
Can you try it?

```
<?php woocommerce_breadcrumb(); ?>
```

This link may help: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce_breadcrumb/

Comment: Yes, that is it! Google just wouldn't give me this result no matter how I've described it.